# How to set up an apt repository?

Tags: linux, repository

I am interested in setting up an apt repository on my server to host some of my packages.

How would I go about doing this? It's a shared server.

Basically, I want to do what Google did  in regards to the way they host Chrome downloads for Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/286

http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/repository-howto/repository-howto#setting-up

http://freshrpms.net/apt/server/

http://www.jejik.com/articles/2006/09/setting_up_and_managing_an_apt_repository_with_reprepro/